# read/write: Illegal seek - client-server C++

Tags: c++, c, client-server, pipe, named-pipes

I found on stackoverflow client-server code (using named pipes) and I modified it to let client send messages in while loop. Althought I get messages from server, I get "Illegal seek" on read/write and Im not sure if its an serious error, if something is really bad here?

**server.cpp**

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   int client_to_server;
   char *myfifo = "/tmp/client_to_server_fifo";

   int server_to_client;
   char *myfifo2 = "/tmp/server_to_client_fifo";

   char buf[BUFSIZ];

   /* create the FIFO (named pipe) */
   mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);
   mkfifo(myfifo2, 0666);

   /* open, read, and display the message from the FIFO */
   client_to_server = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
   server_to_client = open(myfifo2, O_WRONLY);

   printf("Server ON.\n");

   while (1)
   {
      read(client_to_server, buf, BUFSIZ);

      if (strcmp("exit",buf)==0)
      {
         printf("Server OFF.\n");
         break;
      }

      else if (strcmp("",buf)!=0)
      {
         printf("Received: %s\n", buf);
         printf("Sending back...\n");
         write(server_to_client,buf,BUFSIZ);
      }

      /* clean buf from any data */
      memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
   }

   close(client_to_server);
   close(server_to_client);

   unlink(myfifo);
   unlink(myfifo2);
   return 0;
}
```

**client.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
   int client_to_server;
   char *myfifo = "/tmp/client_to_server_fifo";

   int server_to_client;
   char *myfifo2 = "/tmp/server_to_client_fifo";

   char str[BUFSIZ];


   //printf("Input message to serwer: ");
   //scanf("%s", str);


   /* write str to the FIFO */
   client_to_server = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
   server_to_client = open(myfifo2, O_RDONLY);

while(true)
{

   printf("> "); 
   scanf("%s", str);
   write(client_to_server, str, sizeof(str));

   perror("Write:"); //Very crude error check

   read(server_to_client,str,sizeof(str));

   perror("Read:"); // Very crude error check

   printf("From  server: %s\n",str);
}
   close(client_to_server);
   close(server_to_client);

   /* remove the FIFO */

   return 0;
}
```

Example output:

**client** :

```
> hello, server!
Write:: Success
Read:: Illegal seek
From  server: hello,
Write:: Illegal seek
Read:: Illegal seek
> From  server: server!
> its client here!
Write:: Illegal seek
Read:: Illegal seek
From  server: its
Write:: Illegal seek
Read:: Illegal seek
> From  server: client
Write:: Illegal seek
Read:: Illegal seek
> From  server: here!
> > hello, server!
// and so on ...
```

**server** :

```
Server ON.
Received: hello,
Sending back...
Received: server!
Sending back...
Received: its
Sending back...
Received: client
Sending back...
Received: here!
Sending back...
Received: >
Sending back...
Received: hello,
Sending back...
Received: server!
Sending back...
Received: Write::
Sending back...
Received: Success
Sending back...
Received: Read::
Sending back...
Received: Illegal
Sending back...
Received: seek
Sending back...
Received: From
Sending back...
Received: server:
Sending back...
Received: hello,
Sending back...
Received: Write::
Sending back...
Received: Illegal
Sending back...
Received: seek
Sending back...
Received: Read::
Sending back...
Received: Illegal
Sending back...
Received: seek
Sending back...
Received: >
Sending back...
Received: From
Sending back...
Received: server:
Sending back...
Received: server!
Sending back...
Received: >
Sending back...
Received: its
Sending back...
Received: client
Sending back...
Received: here!
Sending back...
Received: Write::
Sending back...
Received: Illegal
Sending back...
Received: seek
Sending back...
Received: Read::
Sending back...
Received: Illegal
Sending back...
Received: seek
Sending back...
Received: From
Sending back...
Received: server:
Sending back...
Received: its
Sending back...
Received: Write::
Sending back...
Received: Illegal
Sending back...
Received: seek
Sending back...
Received: Read::
Sending back...
Received: Illegal
Sending back...
Received: seek
Sending back...
Received: >
Sending back...
Received: From
Sending back...
Received: server:
Sending back...
Received: client
Sending back...
Received: Write::
Sending back...
Received: Illegal
Sending back...
Received: seek
Sending back...
Received: Read::
Sending back...
Received: Illegal
Sending back...
Received: seek
Sending back...
Received: >
Sending back...
Received: From
Sending back...
Received: server:
Sending back...
Received: here!
Sending back...
Received: >
Sending back...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call `perror` if there was no error.

You need to check if the previous function call failed before you can call `perror` or you'll get meaningless error messages when no error actually happened. Functions (usually) aren't required to set `errno` to anything particular if they don't fail.

Comment: thank you it helped :D Also, you made my day with your rhymed answer: "Don't call perror if there was no error" I love that, haha, many thanks, now I will remeber it for forever ^^